# How can we pass multiple initialization, conditions, and increments in FOR loop in C programming?

Tags: c, for-loop

For searching an element in array I divided the array of size 20 in two parts.
a will search from 0-9 and b will search from 10-19. But this code is not working. What is wrong with it?

```
 for(  a=0,b=10; a<9,b<20 ; a++,b++ )
        {
            if(x[a]==n)m=a;break;
            if(x[b]==n)m=b;break;
            if(x[c]==n)m=c;break;
            if(x[d]==n)m=d;break;
        }
```

Comment: `a<9,b<20` ==> `a<9 && b<20`

Comment: `if(x[a]==n)m=a;break;` should be `if(x[a]==n) {m=a;break;}`, even if you write 2 statements on the same line, they are 2 statements, so you need the `{ }` around them.

Comment: what is c and d.

Comment: @WeatherVane why even use that a<9? just check b<20, that will be enough

Comment: @CIsForCookies because `a<9` will be false before `b<20` ;)

Comment: It should be `a<10` instead of `a<9` unless you want to skip positions 9 and 19.

Comment: Can i add more than two variables? If i want to divide the array into 4 parts.           for(  a=0,b=5,c=10,d=15; a<9&&b<10&&c<15&&d<20 ; a++,b++,c++,d++ )
        {
            if(x[a]==n){m=a;break;}
            if(x[b]==n){m=b;break;}
            if(x[c]==n){m=c;break;}
            if(x[d]==n){m=d;break;}
        }

Comment: What's the reason for dividing the array this way?

Comment: Each of the four variables a,b,c,d will search for the required element in the one fourth part of array instead of one variable traversing the whole array.

Comment: But why don't you want to use one variable over the whole array? This whole question seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Taking four variables for searching the array will reduce the searching time.Am i wrong??

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. It's the same total number of operations. Splitting the array can help if you're searching in different threads but that's a lot more advanced.

Comment: Can I suggest a new plan for passing multiple initialization, increments and conditions?  Don't do it.  Whenever you are tempted by 'clever' code, imagine some maintenance engineer, stepping through your code with a debugger, trying to find out why it sometimes fails.  Will they be able to follow it?

Comment: Are you saying that passing multiple variables may not work all the time??

Comment: The point is, code needs maintenance over its lifetime. When making changes or tracking down subtle bugs, "clever" code can bring the work to a halt while one is trying to figure out how it works, what it does, and if the clever code is responsible for other problems. Trust your compiler to do optimizations. When there is a performance issue, profile the code and apply _needed_ optimizations.

Comment: What do you mean profile the code??

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems in your code is in the condition of the `for` loop. It should be:

```
for (a = 0, b = 10; a < 9 && b < 20; a++, b++) { ... }
```

Notice the `&&` between `a < 9` and `b < 20`.

There is also a logic flaw in your `for` loop. Indeed, for each iteration of the loop, `a` and `b` get incremented by 1. This means that when `a = 9`, then `a < 9` will be `false`, and the `for` loop stops. But, when `a = 9`, then `b = 19`, so you will never look at `x[19]` because the loop has already ended.

I think the correct condition is: `a < 10 && b < 20`.

Fact is, you don't really need both `a` and `b`. Look at the following example:

```
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    if (x[a] == n || x[a + 10] == n) {
        m = a;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Also, when you have more than one statement in an `if` block, you must wrap them in `{ ... }` brackets.

```
// Incorrect
if (x[a] == n) m = a; break;

// Correct
if (x[a] == n) {
    m = a;
    break;
}

// Also correct
if (x[a] == n) { m = a; break; }
```

---

As pointed out by other users, you use `c` and `d` inside your loop, but what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors you can try this

```
 for(  a=0,b=10; a<10 && b<20 ; a++,b++ )//&& between conditions and a<10 otherwise 9th element will be skipped
        {
            if(x[a]==n)
             {
              m=a;break;//parenthesis used because it contains 2 statement
             }
            if(x[b]==n)
             {
              m=b;break;//parenthesis used because it contains 2 statement
             }
              //extra statements were removed
        }
```